# Intuition behind a $C^k$ boundary

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I understand the definition of a $C^k$ boundary, but what is the intuition behind such a complicated definition? I've read it over and over and it doesn't really seem to be an intuitive definition.

Edit 1: Here is the definition I was presented with. 
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Let $k\geq 1$. We say that $\Omega$ has a $C^k$ boundary if for every $x_0\in\partial \Omega$ there esists a ball $B(x_0,r)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, an orthogonal transformation $O\in O(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\cap B(0,r)\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f\in C^k$ such that, if we consider the affine transformation $Tx=O(x-x_0)$, then $x\in \Omega\cap B(x_0,r)$ if and only if $y=Tx$ satisfies $y_n>f(y_1,\dots, y_{n-1})$ with $y\in B(0,r)$.

Comment: The usual definition is that locally, the boundary looks like the graph of a $C^k$ function. How is that not intuitive?

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect the definition I was presented with to help you understand a little bit more of what I mean.